# LSTM Forecast timeseries with Hyperparameter Tuner (Random Search) from Keras

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, rnn, hyperparameter-tuning

I want to predict a timeseries with a LSTM Model.

I try to use the Tuner from Keras to find the best hyperparameters.
data_example:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | 600 |
| 2022-01-03 | 640 |
| 2022-01-04 | 605 |
| ... | ... |

And now I want to predict the 2022-01-05 for example.. I just want to predict the next day. And add the predicted day to my sequence.

```
len(df) = 500 (dailyvalues), Trainset=400, Testset=100, n_features = 1, seq_size(n_input)= 8
```

I scale the data (Train- and Testset) from 0 to 1 with MinMaxScaler and user the TimeseriesGenerator to generate the sequences.

```
def build_model(hp):
    
model = Sequential()
     
    model.add(LSTM(hp.Int("input_units", min_value=4, max_value=256, step=8),  
                   return_sequences=True,
                   input_shape=(seq_size,n_features),
                   activation=hp.Choice("activation", ["sigmoid", "tanh"]),
             )
             )
    for i in range(hp.Int('n_layers', 1, 5)):
        
            model.add(LSTM(hp.Int(f'lstm_{i}_units',min_value=4,max_value=256,step=4),
                           return_sequences=True,
                          activation=hp.Choice("activation_" + str(i), ["sigmoid", "tanh"])) 
                 )
model.add(LSTM(hp.Int('input_units_2',min_value=4,max_value=64,step=4)))
    
model.add(Dropout(hp.Float('Dropout_rate',min_value=0,max_value=0.3,step=0.1))) # Maybe remove Dropout
    
model.add(Dense(1))

    learning_rate = hp.Float("lr", min_value=1e-3, max_value=1e-2, sampling="log")
              
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = learning_rate), ## OR "rmsprop"
        loss='mse', 
        metrics= ["mse"]) ## Doesn't make sense, or?

 return model
```

I learned that it only make sense for timeseries to use tanh or sigmoid as activation function. So instead of "ReLu" I only apply "sigmoid" and "tanh".

```
tuner = RandomSearch(
    hypermodel=build_model, 
    objective = "mse", ### ????
    max_trials = 1,
    executions_per_trial = 1, 
    overwrite=True,
    directory = LOG_DIR 
    
    )
```

Is there another objective. I think "val_accuracy" doesn't work.

```
tuner.search(
            train_generator,
            epochs=10,
            batch_size=1, # What exactly means batch_size here?
            validation_data= test_generator)
```

If I print the summary  (`print(tuner.results_summary())`), I get a very small score.

Is there anything I can change or maybe my model doesnt work for timeseries? I found a lot about classification but not about regression.

Comment: Does your model work without the tuner? Did you normalize your data first?